# Exoplayer Next button not clickable when Repeat Mode is REPEAT_MODE_ONE at the last video

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using exoplayer 2.12 and when i reach the last video in the timeline and `player.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE` then Next button is not clickable . What i want is to make some action at that point of time to make next button clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the below method of the [`Player`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html) interface.

```
override fun onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem: MediaItem?, reason: Int) {
       super.onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem, reason)
       val currentIndex = currentWindowIndex
       // check if currentIndex is the last item by comparing with 
       // exoPlayer.mediaItemCount
}
```

This method is called every time the player is switched to a new item or the playlist is changed. You can set the `repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL` if the item is last one in the playlist.